# Is there a way to prevent an @mention notification? Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

I have been looking for a few hours now, and am unable to find any resources on how to do this. *I know that it's possible, as my friend has managed to do it, but they are offline right now so I am unable to ask for help.*

I've tried using the bot to delete the message ASAP, using  `if(msg.mentions.members.has("user.id")) msg.delete()`, and it works, but the notification is still received by the mentioned user.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance, - Citreite

Comment: Have you tried `message.channel.send("Hello, World!")`?

Comment: @Shoejep, it's not that I'm trying to send a message. I'm trying to remove the notification received when someone gets @ mentioned.

Comment: So you want to mention someone --> delete the message that mentioned them --> without showing them any notifications?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect when a user is mentioned, delete the message that mentioned them without showing the mentioned user* any notifications/pings

Comment: Hmm okay, I'm not sure then. Surely that would depend on the mentioned user's Discord settings

Comment: That's what I would have thought too, if my friend didn't somehow do it. But, as I said, they're offline right now, so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Your bot and the person who is being pinged will both get the message at the same time, and the bot deleting it will just make it a ghost ping.